# Need help understanding NpgSQL connection opening process

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

I have been trying to optimize a web service that is using NpgSQL 3.2.7 to connect to a PostgreSQL 9.3 database. Today I installed pgBouncer and noticed when running "select * from pg_stat_activity;" that all of my NpgSQL connections had this query listed:

```
SELECT ns.nspname, a.typname, a.oid, a.typrelid, a.typbasetype,
CASE WHEN pg_proc.proname='array_recv' THEN 'a' ELSE a.typtype END AS type,
CASE
  WHEN pg_proc.proname='array_recv' THEN a.typelem
  WHEN a.typtype='r' THEN rngsubtype
  ELSE 0
END AS elemoid,
CASE
  WHEN pg_proc.proname IN ('array_recv','oidvectorrecv') THEN 3    /* Arrays last */
  WHEN a.typtype='r' THEN 2                                        /* Ranges before */
  WHEN a.typtype='d' THEN 1                                        /* Domains before */
  ELSE 0                                                           /* Base types first */
END AS ord
FROM pg_type AS a
JOIN pg_namespace AS ns ON (ns.oid = a.typnamespace)
JOIN pg_proc ON pg_proc.oid = a.typreceive
LEFT OUTER JOIN pg_type AS b ON (b.oid = a.typelem)
LEFT OUTER JOIN pg_range ON (pg_range.rngtypid = a.oid) 
WHERE
  (
    a.typtype IN ('b', 'r', 'e', 'd') AND
    (b.typtype IS NULL OR b.typtype IN ('b', 'r', 'e', 'd'))  /* Either non-array or array of supported element type */
  )
```

When I run this query in pgAdmin it takes 3 to 5 seconds to complete the second time I run it when everything should be cached. When I have run my code interactively executing the first open command in a web service call has taken 3 to 5 seconds.

Does this run every time a connection is created? It looks to me like this is an expensive query to get some relatively static data. If this does have to run every time a connection is created, does anyone have any suggestions on how to architect around this in a web service? 3 to 5 seconds is just too much overhead for every call to a web service. Does using pooling have any affect on whether or not this query is run?

ADDED: 03/14/2018 
These are log entries I am seeing after creating a table to hold the results of the types query. It runs it successfully and then later cannot find the table for some reason.

2018-03-14 15:35:42 EDT LOG:  duration: 0.715 ms  parse : select nspname,typname,oid,typrelid,typbasetype,type,elemoid,ord from "public"."npgsqltypes"

2018-03-14 15:35:42 EDT LOG:  duration: 0.289 ms  bind : select nspname,typname,oid,typrelid,typbasetype,type,elemoid,ord from "public"."npgsqltypes"

2018-03-14 15:35:42 EDT LOG:  execute : select nspname,typname,oid,typrelid,typbasetype,type,elemoid,ord from "public"."npgsqltypes"

2018-03-14 15:35:42 EDT LOG:  duration: 0.391 ms

2018-03-14 15:35:44 EDT ERROR:  relation "public.npgsqltypes" does not exist at character 71

2018-03-14 15:35:44 EDT STATEMENT:  select nspname,typname,oid,typrelid,typbasetype,type,elemoid,ord from "public"."npgsqltypes"

2018-03-14 15:35:44 EDT LOG:  statement: DISCARD ALL

2018-03-14 15:35:44 EDT LOG:  duration: 0.073 ms

ADDED: 03/15/2018

Explain output of types query:

```
Sort  (cost=3015139.78..3018795.67 rows=1462356 width=213)
  Sort Key: (CASE WHEN (pg_proc.proname = ANY ('{array_recv,oidvectorrecv}'::name[])) THEN 3 WHEN (a.typtype = 'r'::"char") THEN 2 WHEN (a.typtype = 'd'::"char") THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=920418.37..2779709.53 rows=1462356 width=213)
        Hash Cond: (a.oid = pg_range.rngtypid)
        ->  Hash Join  (cost=920417.24..2752289.21 rows=1462356 width=209)
              Hash Cond: ((a.typreceive)::oid = pg_proc.oid)
              ->  Hash Join  (cost=919817.78..2724270.58 rows=1462356 width=149)
                    Hash Cond: (a.typnamespace = ns.oid)
                    ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=919305.50..2687199.40 rows=1462356 width=89)
                          Hash Cond: (a.typelem = b.oid)
                          Filter: (((a.typtype = ANY ('{b,r,e,d}'::"char"[])) AND ((b.typtype IS NULL) OR (b.typtype = ANY ('{b,r,e,d}'::"char"[])))) OR ((a.typname = ANY ('{record,void}'::name[])) AND (a.typtype = 'p'::"char")))
                          ->  Seq Scan on pg_type a  (cost=0.00..694015.89 rows=13731889 width=89)
                          ->  Hash  (cost=694015.89..694015.89 rows=13731889 width=5)
                                ->  Seq Scan on pg_type b  (cost=0.00..694015.89 rows=13731889 width=5)
                    ->  Hash  (cost=388.79..388.79 rows=9879 width=68)
                          ->  Seq Scan on pg_namespace ns  (cost=0.00..388.79 rows=9879 width=68)
              ->  Hash  (cost=465.87..465.87 rows=10687 width=68)
                    ->  Seq Scan on pg_proc  (cost=0.00..465.87 rows=10687 width=68)
        ->  Hash  (cost=1.06..1.06 rows=6 width=8)
              ->  Seq Scan on pg_range  (cost=0.00..1.06 rows=6 width=8)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, this query is issued by Npgsql to load all the types from a PostgreSQL backend - different database can have different data types (due to extensions, user-defined types, etc.).

However, this query is sent only on the first physical connection to a specific database, as identified by its connection string. In other words, if you connect to the same database X times - to the same connection string - you should only see this query being sent once. Npgsql caches this information internally. I just verified that this is the behavior in 3.2.7, are you seeing something else?

Comment: Thanks for the information Shay. I believe the issue is that in load testing all of the connections were being created at once so each connection was brand new. I added creating one connection prior to the larger batch and the query was only run on the creation of the first connection. 

Based on this, can I assume that if in the creation of my web service I create a connection with the same connection string that the application will use and I then close that connection that any connection made after that will not run the query again?

Comment: That's correct. You can do this as part of the "warm-up" phase of your application, prior to actually processing any user requests, to make sure that type loading has already occurred and that the response will be fast. It's true that if you're simultaneously connecting from multiple threads to the same *new* database, it's possible that the types will be loaded more than once (simply because they will race one against the other). This has no negative impact except for the one-off slowdown.

Comment: Shay, I am still having some issues related to this. We have a number of different services using npgsql and the start-up queries can really slow things down. I attempted to run the query and save the results in a table and then I changed the query in npgsql to query that table and recompiled. It worked for a while, but then I began receiving messages that the table I had saved the data in could not be found. I am using this query:
   Select nspname,typname,oid,typrelid,typbasetype,type,elemoid,ord from public.npgsqltypes
Would the table have to be stored in a different schema?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... Npgsql executes a built-in query to load PostgreSQL types from pg_type and other tables. Do you mean you changed Npgsql's code to load types from another table, thinking that it would be more efficient than pg_type? I'd be surprised if that were the case (and in any case it's not an amazing idea to fork Npgsql for this).

Comment: Can you explain why a single, one-off type-loading query is causing you so many issues? Isn't it just something that happens once at the beginning (preferably as part of application startup, before starting to handle requests), and then it's gone?

Comment: I am seeing the query happen more than once from a given web service. I am not certain if something is breaking the connection or if something else is happening, but the query is being run a number of times. I set postgres to log all queries and this query came up a couple of times. We also have several scheduled routines that run at different times of the day and these would be separate applications so this overhead would exist for all of these.

Comment: I took the output of the query that Npgsql runs and selected it into a table and I tried replacing the query with just running against that table. Executing the Npgsql query takes 7 to 12 seconds while executing against this table takes 1.5ms.

Comment: I added some log entries to my original post that show the query first working and then failing. I am unsure as to why it can find the table at one point but not later.

Comment: As I wrote above, if two physical connection are opened to a new database *at the same time*, it's possible to have a race condition where the query will be executed more than once. This can be easily mitigated by establishing a single connection before starting to handle actual requests.

Comment: What version of Npgsql are you using 7-12 seconds isn't normal for loading the types, how many rows exactly do you get back? Do you have a huge amount of enum or composite types or something? There really shouldn't be any reason to replace the built-in query with a table "cache", I'd rather we found the root cause for the slowness rather than looking into your workaround...

Comment: Regarding why your table disappears, I don't think I can help with that - careful check your logs to see when it is dropped and attempt to determine by whom...

Comment: The table doesn't actually get dropped. If I stop the service and restart it, it still uses the table at the beginning and then later indicates that it cannot find the relation. The table name is in all lower case. As far as the operation of the query, I am pasting an explain output in the original question above. We have thousands of schemas which is a requirement that clients have that their data be segregated into a schema so I can't do anything about that. I would also prefer to not have to make changes to the Npgsql code.

Comment: We don't have any custom types in our system. The query returns 135 rows that all come from pg_catalog and information_schema.

Comment: The number of schemas / tables isn't supposed to impact the type loading the query (at least not to make it last 12 seconds...!), especially not if that query is returning a mere 135 rows... Can you confirm you're using the latest version (3.2.7)? I'm asking because some previous versions did have a slow loading issue. Can you also run the Npgsql type loading query manually (e.g. in pgadmin or psql), outside your application, and confirm it takes 7-12 seconds?

Comment: Hello Shay. Yes, I have tested recently with 3.2.6 and 3.2.7 and both have the same issue. I have run the query several times through pgAdmin with the same result. The first time takes 11 to 12 seconds and if I execute it again immediately it will take about 7 seconds since I guess everything is still cached from the previous run. I was assuming it was because the query was making joins between a table with 13 million rows and one with 1.5 million.

Comment: Oh I see, when you were saying lots of schemas/tables you really did mean lots... OK, then I guess the query time makes sense. In Npgsql 4.0 (preview to be released soon) there will actually be a NoTypeLoading mode which bypasses this query (https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/1486) - it was made for others reasons but it could help you as well.

Comment: I had a similar issue, suddenly one day on a normal running production database, wherein this query was completely stuck. For some reason my pg_catalog.pg_attribute table got bloated and I had to force a VACUUM (FULL, FREEZE, VERBOSE, ANALYZE) pg_attribute to fix it. Hope this helps someone.